# How do I create A record in route53 with Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-route53

I'm trying to add simple A record using terraform but encountered "Access Denied error:

```
* aws_route53_record.dns_name: AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:iam::<#>:user/<username> is not authorized to access this resource
        status code: 403, request id: <hash>
```

Based on this link I should not have "provider aws" defined in my file.
I'm not using provider and her's my code:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "new_dns_name" {
  zone_id = "${var.dns_zone_id}"
  name    = "${lookup(var.dns_name, var.region)}"
  type    = "A"
  alias = {
    name                   = "${lower(aws_elb.elb_https.dns_name)}"
    zone_id                = "${aws_elb.elb_https.zone_id}"
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
}
```

I tried it with terraform 0.8.4 and 0.11.3.

User associated with cli keys has below policy but for some reason is not working:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Thank you

Comment: The error is about the permission in your account, no one can help. so fix your aws access key with proper permission first.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are facing is because of permission issue. Suitable permission is not assigned to the user through which you are trying to create  a route 53 A record.

I would highly suggest to look at the permissions under IAM section for the user **arn:aws:iam::<#>:user/** as it does not seem to have the permission to create a route 53 A record.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have permission for managing route53
this is my route53 access

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "route53:*",
                "route53domains:*",
                "cloudfront:ListDistributions",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancers",
                "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEnvironments",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetBucketWebsite",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpoints",
                "ec2:DescribeRegions",
                "sns:ListTopics",
                "sns:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
                "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "apigateway:GET",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/domainnames"
        }
    ]
}
```